# Delphi database: Setting up an array of ADT fields at runtime

Tags: database, delphi

I'm using an in-memory dataset to represent an array of objects.  I've got most of the code figured out to fill the dataset at runtime, but part of my object contains a dynamic array of TPoint records, and I have no idea how to set up the dataset and the loading code to make that work.  I know a TPoint can be represented by an ADT field, but how do I set up an array of ADTs properly and access it at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split it up into a master and detail dataset. The points go in the detail dataset with a record per point.

Answer (score 1):

Too late for me to dig , but you may find your answer towards the end of [this paper on using Fields](http://www.podgoretsky.com/ftp/docs/Delphi/D5/dg/7_fields.html).
BTW, I don't know what your objective is, but I would seriously ponder if a DataSet is the best data structure to hold a list of objects in memory...

Comment: That paper's no help.  All it says is that in an array field, "the field types can be scalar (e.g. float, string), or non-scalar (an ADT)," but with no examples of setting up a non-scalar structure under an array field.

And how else can I make a list of objects work with data-aware controls?